# Dynamically Cluster handling using Google-Maps-for-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

can we send a configuration to the "Google-Maps-for-Rails" plugin to tell is when to trigger the "cluster" mode based on some condition ?

Answer (score 0):

apneadiving helped me to get this fixed.

```
 var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { clusterer: null } });
```